# while using asyncStorage and json.parse() my common variable doesn't update itself

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, async-await

I am creating a React native app. I used asyncStorage. But in my code, variable i goes directly to the last index. Only first codeline is works. variable i take 0,1,2 to the end. But in rest lines, i points last index of for loop.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

you should use await:

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data['+i+']');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```